# Can we change connection dynamicly to Elasticsearch server on Rails App at run time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

I have 2 elasticsearch servers. On my rails app, can I change connection to the Elasticsearch servers at run time?
For example, 
- If user 1 log in the app, it should connect to elasticsearch server 1
- If user 2 log in the app, it should connect to elasticsearch server 2

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to do this? How would you manage connection pool?

Comment: My customer who want to do that. I just investigate it is possible to do that

Answer (score 0):

You can use `randomize_hosts` when creating connection

```
args = {
  hosts: "https://host1.local:9091,https://host2.local:9091",
  adapter: :httpclient,
  logger: (Rails.env.development? || Rails.env.test?) ? Rails.logger : nil,
  reload_on_failure: false,
  randomize_hosts: true,
  request_timeout: 5
}

client = Elasticsearch::Client.new(args)
```

[Randomize hosts doc](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-ruby/tree/master/elasticsearch-transport#randomizing-hosts)

[Here you can read about](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-ruby/tree/master/elasticsearch-transport#connection-selector) a different host selection strategy than round robin. You could implement your own ideas.